# I have python installed but pip isn't working

Tags: python, pip

when I do python --version or python3 --version in my terminal it gives me python2.7.18 and python3.8.9 accordingly. But when I try and use pip, which should be installed with python, I get "zsh: command not found: pip"

ALSO: I cannot find where my python packages are installed. I've tried to delete them but it isn't working. These are the commands I do to uninstall them:

In my Library folder:
`sudo rm -rf Python`

In root:

```
sudo rm -rf “/Applications/Python”
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python
```

even after doing these commands when I do python --version it tells me I have python

Comment: "But when I try and use pip, which should be installed with python" This is not a correct assumption. Depending on how you installed Python, it might not include pip.

Comment: "when I do python --version it tells me I have python" Do `which python` to find where the python executable is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not installed python, lets 1st install python.

Install python:

```bash
brew install python
```

The most recent releases of Python already include pip, so there's no need to install it separately. If your version of Python doesn't have pip included, you should upgrade to the latest version.

```bash
brew update
brew upgrade python
```

Then try your command with "pip"

example:

```bash
pip install Scrapy
```

If the previous doesn't work and, if your python version is Python 3, then try using the "pip3" instead of "pip”

example:

```bash
pip3 install Scrapy
```

Answer (score 6):

To locate the path to your pip and python installations:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

If the which command doesn't find pip, you need to install it.

```
python3 install pip
```

Also, if you have multiple Python projects, it is a good idea to create virtual environments for each of them. This will isolate the modules you install to each project environment.

Comment: thanks this helped, looks like I don't have pip but I have pip3 so the pip install requests worked when I used pip3

Comment: pip3 worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Use pip3 instead of pip in your command line. I struggled to find a solution for this for ages but this change worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

pip is a python library. it doesn't have to have pip.

I suggest you use pyenv which will give you the option to create many virtual environments and install pip by default.

[github pyenv how to instructions](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Often in development one needs to import functionality from libraries outside the canonic python distribution. Different projects need different imports and often different versions of the same library. A virtual environment enables one to curate library versions for specific uses.

Comment: I think I'm too new to everything to do this lmao I don't even know what virtual environments are, I downloaded anaconda and it ended up messing up some stuff for me so I had to delete that and python and restart the entire process, thank you though I'd thumbs up if I could

Comment: This site has a thorough walk through: https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you need to install pip from terminal

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I fixed mine

1 - curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py

2 - nano ~/.zshrc

3 - export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"

4 - source ~/.zshrc